# Which metric to use for Open Telemetry for basic counter

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I have managed to create a Java Application that is able to report the number of message my app processes.

I am able to do this with the **LongCounter** metric type.

But I've noticed some strange behavior that I didn't expect.

Firstly, the instrumentation sends the last known value every 1 minute.
I think this is the interval on the **PeriodicMetricReader**.
What then happens in my metrics dashboard, is that if nothing has happened for the last 10 minutes, it will still show the last value as thought it was happening all the time.

This is not too bad, as I can work with this.

My biggest issue is that if my app shuts down and starts back up, my metrics start from zero again.

But ideally I would like to have to continue.

I found an article that mentions Aggregation Temporality, and I tried setting this to deltaPreferred, but now with this value, the metrics are not showing up at all in my Signoz dashboards.

What I'm trying to do is have a metric, simple number, that shows how many messages my app has processed.
While the app is running it works, but if the app restarts, the counter resets, which is wrong.
And I can't just sum the value, because it keeps sending the last known value every 1 minute. So if I process 1 message, the sum is going to double every 1 minute, or something like that.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the core of my code:

```java
final OtlpHttpMetricExporter metricExporter = OtlpHttpMetricExporter.builder().setEndpoint(otlpEndpoint + "metrics").setAggregationTemporalitySelector(AggregationTemporalitySelector.deltaPreferred()).setCompression("none").build();
final SdkMeterProviderBuilder metricEmitterProviderBuilder = SdkMeterProvider.builder();
metricEmitterProviderBuilder.setResource(resource);

final SdkMeterProviderBuilder metricProviderBuilder = metricEmitterProviderBuilder.registerMetricReader(PeriodicMetricReader.builder(metricExporter).setInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(Math.max(30, 50))).build());

this.meterProvider = metricProviderBuilder.build();
this.meter = this.meterProvider.meterBuilder("my-test").build();
this.counter = this.meter.counterBuilder("my_counter").setUnit("message").build();

/// And later in my code:
/// when my app sees a message it calls
this.counter.add(1);
```

Comment: Your code is fine. An incrementing counter is what you need. The issues you mention need to be solved in the tool that exploit these metrics. Typically with Prometheus, there are functions that handle reset of a counter automatically and also there are functions to compute a rate from an increasing counter, etc...